# Git não reconhece alterações em arquivos que tenham a palavra "anexo" no nome

Tags: git, commit

Estou com um problema e não consegui achar uma logica por traz dele, tenho meu repositorio aqui antigo, varias pessoas atuam nele porem em alguns pc's os arquivos JS que tenham a palavra anexo no nome não reconhece modificações.

Esses arquivos são antigos, mais de 5 anos, a equipe trabalha neles normalmente, porem as vezes começa esse problema, faço uma alteração e não é reconhecida pelo git para fazer o commit e push. Ressaltando que acontece apenas com os arquivos js que possuem a palavra "anexo" no nome e não acontece com todos na equipe, atualmente apenas um computador esta acontecendo isso, ja chegamos ao ponto de formatar a maquina e baixar tudo novamente e o problema persistiu nesse pc.

Alguem consegue ver alguma logica nisso ou passou por algo parecido?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: já olhou o `.gitignore`?

Comment: pode olhar o arquivo `.gitignore`. E ver se possui algum glob que faz o match do arquivo.

Answer (score 1):

O [`git-check-ignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore) é útil para descobrir o exclude pattern de um arquivo específico.

```
> git check-ignore -v .projectile
/Users/viniciusbrasil/.gitignore:5:.projectile  .projectile
```

No exemplo acima, o arquivo `.projectile` estava sendo ignorado pelo `.gitignore` global na linha 5. Aí basta editar o arquivo de exclusão.